# convert code meant for ordered list to table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying to figure out how to convert this codes to work for table td cells in a column. I seek help with regards to this.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable({
        stop: function() {
            var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
            $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
                var index = $( "#selectable li" ).index( this );
                result.append( " #" + ( index + 1 ) );
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the var index line in the code with this:

```
var index = $( "#selectable td" ).index( this );
```

Make sure the table has an id #selectable